# Предупреждение: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php

> `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\server\xampp\htdocs\checklogin.php`

Подскажите, как ее исправить, буду благодарен...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы что-то вывели на страницу до вызова session_start(). Так делать нельзя.

Answer (score 4):

Перед вызовом session_start(); не должно быть выводов текста, если вы ничего не выводите, удалите все пробелы перед <?php, если ошибка не исчезает, перекодируйте документ в utf-8 без BOM.